# Free alternative to "Depression evaluation" tool from ArcHydroTools

Tags: qgis, python, raster, software-recommendations, whitebox-gat

Is there any free program or package that has the same function as `Depression evaluation` tool in ArcHydro tool from ArcGIS?

I am currently working on extracting depressions from DEMs as well as their respective drainage area. Depression analysis function does exactly what I want, which is defining the depressions in DEM and the drainage area of each depression. However, I no longer have access to ArcGIS.

I know that I can extract the depressions using the `stochastic depression analysis` tool from Whitebox tools. Also, I am familiar with QGIS, but I was unable to find the same thing in either QGIS or Whitebox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do exactly what `depression evaluation` function from ArcHydroTools does but using the free ***[Whitebox tool](https://jblindsay.github.io/ghrg/Whitebox/download.shtml)*** software.

The following steps need to be done to get the depressions and their respective drainage area from the DEM.

1. use the `sink` function to extract the depressions from the DEM. This function requires the DEM as the input raster.
2. use the `D8 Flow Pointer` function to get the D8 flow direction. This function requires the DEM as the input raster.
3. use the `watershed` function to delineate the drainage area for each depression. The resulting rasters from `sink` and `D8 Flow Pointer` are used as inputs. Using this combination, the function `watershed` delineates the DEM considering that each depression is a separate outlet
   [image]

The final product is attached below, which is almost identical to the output of the `depression evaluation` function from ArcHydroTools. The ***[Whitebox tool](https://jblindsay.github.io/ghrg/Whitebox/download.shtml)*** is available as stand-alone software, an R package, and a python package, which makes it very useful to be used on different platforms and OS.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I have ArcGIS and still prefer using [TauDEM](http://hydrology.usu.edu/taudem/taudem5/index.html) to do the job. E.g. this bat-file

```
cd c:\Program Files\TauDEM\TauDEM5Exe
mpiexec -n 8 pitremove -z "C:\scratch\dem" -fel ""C:\scratch\Filled.tif"
mpiexec -n 8 D8FlowDir -fel "C:\SCRATCH\Filled.tif" -p "C:\SCRATCH\FDIR.tif" -sd8 "C:\SCRATCH\Slope.tif"
mpiexec -n 8 AreaD8 -p "C:\SCRATCH\FDIR.tif" -ad8 "C:\SCRATCH\FACC.tif" -nc
mpiexec -n 8 Threshold -ssa "C:\SCRATCH\FACC.tif" -src "C:\SCRATCH\STREAMS.tif" -thresh 10000
mpiexec -n 4 StreamNet -fel "C:\SCRATCH\Filled.tif" -p "C:\SCRATCH\FDIR.tif" -ad8 "C:\SCRATCH\FACC.tif" -src "C:\SCRATCH\STREAMS.tif" -ord "C:\SCRATCH\Filledord.tif" -tree "C:\SCRATCH\Filledtree.txt" -coord "C:\SCRATCH\Filledcoord.txt" -net "C:\SCRATCH\Fillednet.shp" -w "C:\SCRATCH\Filledw.tif"
```

Is equivalent to:

[image]

but works much faster.

Comment: Does this calculate the overall drainage area for the basin?
Or, it does calculate the drainage area (contributing area) for individual depressions?

Comment: Perhaps go through tools shown in the model to understand what it does. You can find depressions by using (Filled - DEM)>0. Etc. I also suggest you read TauDEM documentation.

Comment: When I tried your approach, it gave me the subbasins of the study area, which is not what I want. I need to get the drainage area for each individual depression. I found a way to do exactly what I want using the Whitebox tool. check my answer below.

Comment: You can specify depressions as input to Streamnet, simply replace Stream.tif.